# Unable to load assets from AWS S3 over https?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

AWS S3 Bucket name is stagingfiles.example.com, I am using cloudfront for serving assets.

When site loadded over http, assets(js & css) loaded properly, but when its loaded over https, assets were not loaded. The following error was shown in google chrome web console.

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://staging.example.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://stagingfiles.example.com/assets/home_page-abb03872b937f39d93d8477b6bb80a09.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure cloudfront to serve assets via https:// as well. Also you need to load assets in your web page via https://. This is not an issue with S3 or cloudfront but a general browser behavior.

BTW: The error message was rather clear about that.

Comment: @alias500  "cloudfront to serve assets via https:// as well"  the question is how to do that? 
I have in production rb 
    `config.action_controller.asset_host = "https://d270kx9p29trh.cloudfront.net"`
but still no luck